# Azure DocumentDb without C#, authorization, and just use straight Angular

Tags: angularjs, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I've scoured Google and StackOverflow with no avail. I'm new to [DocumentDB](http://www.documentdb.com) and just imported data from my SQL instance; so far, so good.

My documents require no security and I'm looking for a setting (?) on Azure that bypasses the extra garbage in the URL and token (from the keys, i.e. master key) or some solution to keep this SIMPLE.

In short, I'm looking to create a pure AngularJs solution that doesn't require the extra auth baggage and curious what needs to be done.  (A proxy on my site like WebApi does not work for me, i.e.  **Microsoft.Azure.DocumentClass** shouldn't be required for such simple access.)

Comment: FYI without that "extra garbage" of authentication/etc, there would be nothing stopping anyone from doing anything with your database: Adding collections, storing data, retrieving data, deleting data, modifying data critical to your app, consuming your Request Unit allocation, causing your app to not work properly, running up your bill, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are a javascript guy, I recommend that you use Azure's node.js service (web app in Azure termonology) and stand up a little proxy service. You may be able to use npm package hoxy with just a bit of configuration. There's also the popular json-proxy npm package. You could even just use node-restify or express.js and write the code to do proxying yourself.

With either of these, you could then also implement a minimal auth system so you don't run the risks that David Makogon mentions.

To elaborate, the idea is that you pretend like you are hitting DocumentDB's REST API directly from your browser. However, the URL is for your proxy service rather than the DocumentDB end point. Also leave off the DocumentDB auth stuff when calling from your browser but add a bit of your own auth. I recommend basic auth which is supported by Angular and really easy to implement in your service. Your proxy then confirms that the auth from the browser was correct and uses your DocumentDB master key to hit DocumentDB. Your proxy is basically substituting your basic auth for full DocumentDB master key access.

Don't hard code your DocumentDB master key into your proxy code. Rather, put it in an environment variable (a config option in portal.azure.com) that your service references (process.env.DOCUMENT_DB_KEY).

In the simplest form, you could store also store the one valid username and password in environment variables. If you need more than a few logins, you may want to store that in the DocumentDB database. Clear text password storage is probably fine for you but I would be remiss if I didn't recommend that you store a salted hash using node's built-in crypto (crypto.pbkdf2) rather than the clear text password. You could skip it for your use case, but you should probably use https rather than http. Azure supports this but you have to get your own certificate.

I'm in the process of turning my current more sophisticated API front-end for DocumentDB into an npm package. I'll be glad to share that with you when it's ready. Alternatively, it wouldn't take me long to code up the super simple one you outline and publish it to npm on spec.

Comment: Larry, thank you for the helpful insight - you too Ryan.  I'm probably better off exporting the data to static .json files and publishing to a CDN because I see that we have no need for a middle-ware proxy. (I'm a full-stack guy)

Answer (score 1):

There is no setting that allows anonymous access to DocumentDB